# node js set style css page and fill data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

here is a list of folders and files i have

```
public__
         |_generate-todo.js
         |_index.js
         |_style.css
views__
         |_404
         |main
users-data.json
server.js
```

**Problem 1:** I have done with view now i want to assign ***public*** folder style sheet and js files to my main handlebar page to generate better layout

**problem 2:** I have to fill my main handle drop down select list with json data in  **user-data.json** file

**what i done:**

```
   var path = require('path');
   var express = require('express');
   var exphbs = require('express-handlebars');

   var app = express();
   var usersData = require('./users-data');
   var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

   // Use Handlebars as the view engine for the app.
   app.engine('handlebars', exphbs({ defaultLayout: 'main' }))
   app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

   // Define the port to run on
    app.set('port', 3000);

   app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.render('index-page');
   });

    app.use(function(req, res) {
      res.redirect('404-page');
     });

    var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    var port = server.address().port;
        console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
    });
```

anybody help me with these problems

Comment: Set you static folder with your styles, images etc, in your server `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public');`
Then in your file ensure when calling them you add a `/` like
`<link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: i have edited question this one was done already by self see the problem this is what  i want to ask

Comment: You cannot edit the question to a whole new question. What you can do is revert your edit, accept an answer that relates to the original question and solves the original question. Open a new question for a new problem! Also open a new question for each problem!

Comment: actually problem is that i was not clearly able to mention as i am new

Comment: sir happy now i am posting again

Comment: I've rolled this back to the original question. If you have a new question, use a new post please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*The following answer relates to a previous version of the question.*

[Here you can see the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/40764285/1)

**Solution Problem 1:**

You have to serve your `/public` folder with express.

You can do it with the following code:

`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));`

Then you can add your `css` an `js` files from your public directory as usual. (Don't use `/public` in your href or src statement.)

So you can add this to your html file(s):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" type="text/css">
<script src="/index.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/generate-todo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Lookup express.static() docs for reference: [express.static() documentation](http://expressjs.com/de/starter/static-files.html)

**Solution Problem 2:**

You have already a `require` statement for your json file in your `server.js`:

```
var usersData = require(./users-data.json);
```

You can pass it to your template in the res.render() method:

```
// pass a local variable to the view
res.render('your-template', { usersData: usersData });
```

Now you can use it as `usersData` in your template on your dropdown-select. (e.g. `{{ usersData.something }}`)

See [express.js res.render() documentation](http://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#res.render) for reference.

Comment: but not rendering layouts of main handlebar see above 2 problems second one is your relevant and close

Comment: main handle bar as layout

Comment: yes its rendring main handle view but why it is not adding title like 'ToDoIt <user>' and for error 'ToDoIt'  only

Comment: Sir title problem still not Handled